# Unite two where clauses

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
# models/micropost.rb

def self.from_users_followed_by(user)
  followed_user_ids = "SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
                       WHERE follower_id = :user_id"
  where("user_id IN (#{followed_user_ids}) OR
        user_id = :user_id", user_id: user.id)
end

def self.in_reply_to(user)
  where("content LIKE :user_login", user_login: '@' + user.login + '%')
end


# models/user.rb

def feed
  Micropost.from_users_followed_by(self).in_reply_to(self) # AND
end
```

It works, but i need to have microposts from users followed by user OR(not AND!) in reply to user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I know how to do this would be `(Micropost.from_users_followed_by(self) + Micropost.in_reply_to(self)).uniq`

You can also use the Squeel gem (https://github.com/ernie/squeel/), which supports OR clauses - but I'm not sure if Squeel lets you use the OR operator on existing scopes; it may or may not be an efficient solution to your trouble.

Comment: It works, but it returns an Array, while i want to have a Relation (my mistake, i should have described it). Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Comment: I'm having a little trouble getting it to run locally, but I hear anecdotally that you might be able to use ".merge" rather than "+" to get a relation object back. YMMV.